# How to put two links on the installer?

Tags: hyperlink, inno-setup

How can i put two links on the wizard? i have only one at the moment but would like to have links for:

https://www.facebook.com/groups/jyrka98sMods/

`and`

http://jyrka98.webs.com/

This is the code i have for 1 link:

```
  [Code]
    var
      LinkLabel: TLabel;

    procedure LinkClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      ErrorCode: Integer;
    begin
      ShellExec('', 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/jyrka98sMods/', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, 
        ErrorCode);
    end;

    procedure InitializeWizard;
    begin
      LinkLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
      LinkLabel.Parent := WizardForm;
      LinkLabel.Left := 8;
      LinkLabel.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - 
        LinkLabel.ClientHeight - 8;
      LinkLabel.Cursor := crHand;
      LinkLabel.Font.Color := clBlue;
      LinkLabel.Font.Style := [fsUnderline];
      LinkLabel.Caption := 'Visit jyrka98s mods facebook page';
      LinkLabel.OnClick := @LinkClick;
    end;

    procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
    begin
      LinkLabel.Visible := CurPageID <> wpLicense;
    end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance this way:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
const
  FBLink = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/jyrka98sMods/';
  MPLink = 'http://jyrka98.webs.com/';
var
  FBLinkLabel: TLabel;
  MPLinkLabel: TLabel;

procedure FBLinkClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('', FBLink, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;

procedure MPLinkClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('', MPLink, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  FBLinkLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  FBLinkLabel.Parent := WizardForm;
  FBLinkLabel.Left := 8;
  FBLinkLabel.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - 
    FBLinkLabel.ClientHeight - 8;
  FBLinkLabel.Cursor := crHand;
  FBLinkLabel.Font.Color := clBlue;
  FBLinkLabel.Font.Style := [fsUnderline];
  FBLinkLabel.Caption := 'Visit jyrka98s mods facebook page';
  FBLinkLabel.OnClick := @FBLinkClick;

  MPLinkLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  MPLinkLabel.Parent := WizardForm;
  MPLinkLabel.Left := FBLinkLabel.Left + FBLinkLabel.Width + 8;
  MPLinkLabel.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight -
    MPLinkLabel.ClientHeight - 8;
  MPLinkLabel.Cursor := crHand;
  MPLinkLabel.Font.Color := clBlue;
  MPLinkLabel.Font.Style := [fsUnderline];
  MPLinkLabel.Caption := 'Visit jyrka98s mods pack page';
  MPLinkLabel.OnClick := @MPLinkClick;  
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  FBLinkLabel.Visible := CurPageID <> wpLicense;
  MPLinkLabel.Visible := CurPageID <> wpLicense;
end;
```